# click through different levels and then go back to the start + Html + jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a chart, in html, that I can click on and go through the levels, using jQuery.
It first appears at the top level. 
When one of the lines is selected in the charts it will draw the next level down in the same chart. 
Now this works but I think the algorithm could possibly be improved.

What I want to do is be able to draw the chart again at the top level on clicking on the chart on the 4th time, so basically go back to the start. Can anyone advise the best way of doing this?

here is a rough idea of my algorithm.

```
var countlevel = 1; 
$(document).on('nameSelect',function(evt) {
    if(evt.chartname == "chart11" && countlevel==1) { 
        //draw chart at level 2         
    }
    if(evt.chartname == "chart11" && countlevel==2) { 
            //draw chart at level 3
    }
    if(evt.chartname == "chart11" && countlevel==3) { 
            //draw chart at level 4
    }
    countlevel++;
});
```

I was thinking of adding something like this but i can't get this to work and i think there might be a better way of doing this:

```
if(evt.chartname == "chart11" && countlevel==4) { 
//draw chart at level 3

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the modulo reset your `countlevel` variable

```
var countlevel = 1; 
$(document).on('nameSelect',function(evt) {
    if(evt.chartname == "chart11"){
        if (countlevel == 0) {
            // draw chart at lvl 1
        } else if (countlevel == 1) {
            // draw chart at lvl 2
        }  else if (countlevel == 2) {
            // draw chart at lvl 3
        } else if (countlevel == 3) {
            // draw chart at lvl 4
        }
    }
    countlevel++;
    countlevel %= 4;
});
```

Comment: hmm that simple, does count level have to start at 0 in your model?

Comment: Assuming that the first time the chart is already drawn, it should be be 1.